# Как правильно писать? (2)

Tags: орфография, жаргон, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Как правильно: *нольпяшка*, *ноль пяшка* или *ноль-пяшка*?

Бутылка размером в 0,5 литра (у вас это называется поллитровка, у нас это называется нольпяшка), и вот мне одна женщина утверждает, что пишется раздельно, хотя я уверена, что слитно, ибо прилагательное словосочетание, а значит слитно, но мне надо убедиться, права ли я, чтобы потом, если что, разъяснили.

Comment: Короче я накосячила и ответила не там,где надо

Comment: Перенесите что считаете нужным в вопрос и удалите "ответ". Всё исправимо. :) У вас это где?

Comment: В любом случае, если Вы настаиваете на этом слове, в словаре его нету, поэтому однозначно ответить на этот вопрос не получится. Скажу лишь, что раздельное написание совсем сложно чем-то оправдать.

Comment: Ой, спасибо большое❣️

Answer (score 1):

Без Гугла не понял, о чём идёт речь. :)

Я считаю, что такие слова коверкают язык, поэтому если уж использовать, то хоть тоже жаргонное, но более нормальное слово *поллитровка* (если нужно существительное).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуем "отследить" нестандартное словообразование.
Ноль [целых] пять [десятых] литра = ноль пять [литра] = ноль пять.

*Он не взял **ноль пять** перцовки* (М. Зосимкина).

Если сравнивать с пол-литра (обычный объем), то получается **ноль-пяшка.**
Если использовать другие ассоциации (поллитра — поллитровка; сто рублей — сторублёвка), то получается вариант **нольпяшка.**

Чаще всего встречается вариант **слитного** написания (*...в планы мои поездка не входила, в моём рюкзаке была только **нольпяшка** воды...*).

Через дефис тоже имеется:
*— А пока, вот, — я достал из рюкзака **«ноль-пяшку»** чачи, которую привез мне Вовка...*
А. Тихомиров. Глухарь в белом оперении

Согласна с *Артёмом Луговым*: раздельное оформление слова тут "не катит".
Если бы мне пришлось выбирать, я бы написала слитно.